# Silly fraction question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, economics

I've got

$$
MPK'=\frac{1-d}{1+r+x}
$$

But I need it in the form

$$
MPK'=d+r+x
$$

How do I bring those up top?

Comment: You can't unless you somehow know that $1-d=(1+r+x)(d+r+x)$

Comment: If you want to keep the values for all vaiables $d, r, x$ it is like @HagenvonEitzen said. A rearrangement will usually change some of values.

Comment: Correction, thats changing
$$
\frac{MPK'}{1+r+x}=\frac{d-1}{1+r+x}
$$

Into the second form. Not sure if that helps, but I messed up my derivation in the first case... Actually might be able to figure this out now.